# Low latency audio from RasPi server to an Android app

Tags: android, audio, stream, raspberry-pi, latency

I'm using a Raspberry Pi to stream audio from a USB converter to my Android app, but the big problem is that I need it to have no latency.

I've already tried Icecast w/ ices2/darkice but the latency was too big. I'm not able to work with GStreamer; GStreamer in RPi to GStreamer in a PC client was OK, but I dont't managed to install it on Android.
Now I wrote my own Server in Java using UDP to transmit the data, but i get 1+ seconds of latency and I need it to be less.

Does anyone have an idea of what can I use in RPi to manage the latency problem? Thanks!